# Pandas and interactive plots - small interactive surface plot created by iplot on dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, cufflinks

I'm trying to draw interactive charts with using pandas, plotly, cufflinks and iplot on example dataframe data created by me. My chart is very small and unreadable.

I've written few line of code like below in jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import cufflinks as cf
%matplotlib inline
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5], 'y': [10,20,30,20,10], 'z': [500,400,300,200,100]})
df3.iplot(kind='surface')
```

The results is sufrace chart:

[image]

I tried to use few parameters in order to increase size but it causes only resizing padding of actual chart. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016712/plotly-change-figure-size-by-calling-cufflinks-in-pandas) to be very helpful. `layout1 = cf.Layout(    height=300,width=200)`